# For what types of A and B is the simple assignment statement A = B legal in C++ but not Java?

Tags: java, c++, compilation

Got this question in my homework, tried googling but no luck there either.

For what types of A and B is the simple assignment statement A = B legal in C++ but
not Java?

Comment: I wonder the sense of this question.  C++ and Java are two different languages.  The `=` sign is *not* the same thing in Java as in C++ if you're talking about objects.  It is the `=` that confuses many Java programmers when learning C++, and vice-versa.

Comment: I agree.   The bigger problem is that assignment statements of the form `A = B` affecting objects are often legal (depending on the design of the object) in both languages, but have different effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything with a `boolean` assignment should do. In C++, true is any non-zero value. In Java, `boolean` is a type (and that type is checked). For example,

```
bool a = 1;
```

is legal C++. But

```
boolean a = 1;
```

is not legal Java. Also, as noted by [@akuzmiykh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943159/for-what-types-of-a-and-b-is-the-simple-assignment-statement-a-b-legal-in-c/60943187#comment107820377_60943187) the reverse is also true, that is

```
int a = true;
```

is legal C++, but not legal Java.

Comment: Just in addition: The other way around works as well in C++; `int x = true;` or `int x = false;`.