# For what types of A and B is the simple assignment statement A = B legal in Java but not C#?

Tags: java, c#, compilation

Got this question in my homework, tried googling but no luck there either.

**For example, simple assignment statement A = B legal in C++ but not Java:**

bool a = 1; **is legal C++.**

**But**

boolean a = 1; **is not legal Java.**

**I want to know**
For what types of A and B is the simple assignment statement A = B legal in Java but not C#?

Comment: Try it, and report back if you have questions about *your* code.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense as a homework question, unless the instructor already went over it in class or the textbook already has the answer.  Otherwise, it's a "read the mind of the instructor" question.

Comment: In any case, since the instructor clearly intended for you to do the work of solving this problem yourself, I've voted to close your question.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63976292/102937), where you apparently attempted to ask this question  once already.

Comment: I believe that someone who understands the two programming languages ​​well knows the answer, so I posted it here

Comment: A guy posted something like that and was answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943159/for-what-types-of-a-and-b-is-the-simple-assignment-statement-a-b-legal-in-c

Comment: That question wasn't received especially well either, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of generic classes is different in Java and C#, so in Java it is possible to assign a typed collection to a raw collection (though getting a warning) or to a collection with a wildcard (thanks Johannes Kuhn):

```java
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
List<Integer> inums = nums;
      
ArrayList<String>  strs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "bb", "ccc"));
List<String> istrs = strs;
      
ArrayList<?> list = nums;
List ilist = inums;
      
System.out.println("implementation: " + list);
System.out.println("interface: " + ilist);
      
list = strs;
ilist = istrs;

System.out.println("implementation: " + list);
System.out.println("interface: " + ilist);
```

This code will work and print lists.

In C# it's possible to assign generic implementation to raw interface reference.

However, generic interface cannot be assigned to raw interface and generic implementation cannot be assigned to raw implementation as shown below:

```cs
static void Main() {
    List<int> nums = new List<int>();
    nums.Add(1);
    nums.Add(2);
    nums.Add(3);
    nums.Add(4);
    IList<int> inums = nums;
    
    List<string> strs = new List<string>();
    strs.Add("aa");
    strs.Add("bbb");
    IList<string> istrs = strs;
    
    System.Collections.IList ilist = nums; // works: generic implementation assignable to raw interface
    ilist = inums; // fails:  error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>' to `System.Collections.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
 
    // assigning generic implementation to raw implementation
    System.Collections.ArrayList alist = nums; // fails: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to `System.Collections.ArrayList'
    // List list = nums; // error CS0305: Using the generic type `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires `1' type argument(s)

    Console.WriteLine("list="+ alist);
        
    ilist = istrs; // fails: error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>' to `System.Collections.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    alist = strs;  // fails: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to `System.Collections.ArrayList'
    Console.WriteLine("list="+ ilist);
}
```

Comment: You can also use `List<?>` instead.

Comment: In Java - yes, but in C# generics are more "type-safe"

Comment: Try `IList` instead.

Comment: IList needs to be typed anyway: `error CS0305: Using the generic type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' requires `1' type argument(s)`  And afair there's no direct equivalent of Java wildcard in C# generics.

Comment: Wrong type. Try `System.Collections.IList`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, I updated the answer, thanks for pointing out  the inaccuracy.